# SQLlite Update query always return 0 in android project

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, xamarin

I am trying to update database on button click. but it always returns 0, and database is not updated.

```
string query4 = "update Praysettings set value ='" + LocName + "' where id =52;";

db2.ExecuteQuery(query4);

public void ExecuteQuery(string query) 
{
    string dbPath = Path.Combine (
        System.Environment.GetFolderPath (
            System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
        ),
        "tzmpo_t.rar"
    );

    if (File.Exists(dbPath)) {
        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
        {
            int a = db.Execute(query);
            db.Close();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider if what you posted could really help to find your issue. Maybe you have some information Logcat. And if not, your database has a scheme you could share. Anyway `id =52` does not look right. Usually this id field is called `_id`.

Comment: it is something related to parameter Locname length, when i reduced length, it got successfully updated, My field type is VARCHAR, what is maximum limit of varchar.

Comment: [SQLite does not impose any length restrictions](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) Could you add your SQL scheme please?

Comment: There supposed to be _id or none of the built in stuff will work.

Answer (score 0):

The value already exists? If you are not updating the value then there won't be affected rows. Check if that is the case.

Here is the code I use, may be it helps you:

```
    private void OpenConnection()
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            if (_connection == null || _connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed || _connection.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
            {
                _connection = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + DbPath);
                _connection.SetPassword(DbKey);
                _connection.Open();
            }
        }
    }

    private int ExecuteNonQuery(string query)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            OpenConnection();
            int rowcount = 0;
            using (var command = _connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = query;
                try
                {
                    rowcount = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Logger.Error("ExecuteNonQuery", e.Message + ". Query:" + query);
                }
                command.Dispose();
            }

            return rowcount;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is something related to parameter Locname length, when i reduced length, it got successfully updated, My field type is VARCHAR, what is maximum limit of varchar.

Comment: Ok so you are not updating the data because you are getting a SQL error. I don't think you are using VARCHAR, maybe you are using TEXT, right? If not, try using TEXT.